# Raphael loading SVG file from server

Tags: raphael

I need to render the SVG file in the browser which is placed on the server. What I do is make an Ajax call to the SVG and render the response in the DOM. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't works in IE-8. 
I know IE-8 doesn't supports SVG. Can we use RaphaelJS to cater the same situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [something like this](http://readysetraphael.com/) to convert your `SVG` to `RaphaelJS`?

I just tried it with the [classic svg tiger](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aGhostscript_Tiger.svg) and it [worked well](http://jsfiddle.net/CLdyd/).

**EDITS**

You could also do the conversion from SVG to Raphael on the fly.  See [here](https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic) and [here](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import).

Comment: Unable to access the link, because of the corporate firewall. Just want to add that the SVG file on the server may get updated at regular intervals via some other service. Will your approach will still be valid?

Comment: @AnupVasudeva, see edits. There are plugins to convert the SVG to Raphael on the fly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please confirm whether this is working in IE-8, because it is not working on my system. And I think, not all features of SVG are supported in IE-8.

Comment: @AnupVasudeva, I tried my above jsfiddle in IE10 set to document mode 8.  It rendered properly using VML (Raphael draws in VML for IE < 9 and SVG for IE >= 9).